# Papervision3D: Line3D updating onEnterFrame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d

I'm updating the start and end points of a Line3D object in Papervision3D. The end result works fine but there seems to be a lag from when I move the objects and for the line to redraw in the right position. I'm using the following code:

```
connectingLine.v0.x = startDisObj.sceneX;
connectingLine.v0.y = startDisObj.sceneY;
connectingLine.v0.z = startDisObj.sceneZ;
connectingLine.v1.x = endDisObj.sceneX;
connectingLine.v1.y = endDisObj.sceneY;
connectingLine.v1.z = endDisObj.sceneZ;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That code should be fast enough, perhaps the problem is somewhere else in your code (I'll guess that you're probably doing a lot of unnecessary processing or something).

Comment: are you doing this before or after the render call to papervision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using singleRender() and it seems by adding an extra call to singleRender() before the above script but after the camera move has solved the problem.

Thanks.